# How to restrict a type when defining, but have the real object type by just the restricted version?

Tags: typescript

Given:

```
interface Customer {
  name: string
  address: string
  phone: string
}

type PartialRecord<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]?: T
}

// For this, I want the keys to be only fields that are in customer, but I need the derived type to be the fields  
// that are actually defined here - not the full set of those in customer
const editableFields: PartialRecord<keyof Customer, string> = {
    name: 'The customer name',
} as const;

type EditableCustomer = Pick<Customer, keyof typeof editableFields>

// This gives an error - missing address and phone
const x: EditableCustomer = {
    name: 'Bob'
}
```

The idea is I want to have a function `foo(c: EdiableCustomer)` that has access just to the fields that are actually editable, based on what labels are defined in `editableFields`, but I want to maintain the type restriction in the definition of `editableFields` to only be the keys of `Customer`, but still have the resulting type be just the union of what is actually defined, and not the entirety of `Customer`.

The real usage is a bit more complicated than this, but this is my best shot at distilling the problem down into a minimal case. I feel like there is a template solution to this to define `editableFields` as some type that is inheritable from the `PartialRecord`, but my template-fu is not great in TS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a perfect case for the `satisfies` operator:

```
const editableFields = {
    name: 'The customer name',
} satisfies PartialRecord<keyof Customer, string>;
```

The satisfies keyword tells typescript that it should infer `editableFields`'s type based on the actual values written (in this case, that type is `{ name: string; }`), but if the resulting type isn't compatible with `PartialRecord<keyof Customer, string>;` you want an error to be shown.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbaZAbwChlkQ4CAuZbKUAczOTgBM2oJNNb6mWABwAWOEBD5gGIZgF8SJMAE9BKAApwoYYHAA2AJQgIcUNgB4A0sggAPSCDaZkAawhKcMViCUAaZABUAPmQAXmIWcgBtNWRQZAsAXQB%20Wn8SeRJjEGxrNmAwOAAjXQgAMWAIXUdQ8PJyShpkAHJ-YRQELFwCKAoqCCafdLo4bUwYCqcNLR0DIxNzV3dPDGx8aD9%20GUCAbgVlVWQAUTyC4ogVrsIwtWAEZzMLtag-RY9kfYg3iBOikvLKxyBBRZHI2WjHfK-c6dJ41Uh1XqNJoAIRwhSa6SAA)

[Documentation of Satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html)

Comment: Ah I do recall hearing about that being added - thanks, that works great!